# Amember set price in form

Tags: php, html, forms, amember

How can i set the price in my costum form, that will bill the users every month?

I've tried manually editing this, but without any luck ( data-second_price ):

```
 <input type="hidden" data-first_price="35.00" data-second_price="228.00" name="product_id" id="product_id-0" value="3-3" />
```

How can i remove the product and set the price manually in my form code?
data_first_price will always be 35, but not the monthly.

Comment: I sure don't understand what you are talking about...

Comment: Have you experimence with a-member?

Comment: Oops ! I thought it was a typo for "A member". Sorry (never heard of aMember before).